# How can you derive score test under nonlinear null hypothesis with nuisance parameter?

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, estimation, hypothesis-testing, parameter-estimation

Suppose I have a multiple linear regression of the form:

$$y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_{i1} + \beta_2 x_{i2} +\beta_3 x_{i3}+\epsilon$$

Then suppose I am interested in testing this set of hypotheses:

$$H_0: \beta_1 *\beta_2 = 0$$
$$H_A: \beta_1 *\beta_2 \neq 0$$

I am interested in deriving a score test statistic for this hypothesis.  I understand that I need to derive this under the null hypothesis.  However, I am under the impression that score tests do not work for nonlinear hypotheses of this form, correct?  Additionally, you see that there is a nuisance parameter to also take into consideration: $\beta_3$.

Any input would be much appreciated, thank you!

Update: this is quite similar to my question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4047334/how-to-derive-test-statistic-under-composite-null-hypothesis).  However, this setting has a nuisance parameter, whereas the other does not.

Comment: @callculus, yes, thank you!

Comment: Ok. Then you should accept the answer.

Comment: Can you post as an answer rather than a comment so I can accept it?  Otherwise, I upvoted it.  Please let me know if I am misunderstood about how to use this, thanks!

Comment: I meant the answer of linked question. You have already accepted the answer. So everything is fine. I´ve upvoted the answer and the question.

Comment: Got it, thank you!  So does it not matter in this setting that there is a nuisance parameter here?  That is why I assumed this was a different question.

Comment: I dont´t think that there is a difference.